# Update and select in one operation in MSSQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table with a column `ID` varchar(255) and a `done` bit.
I want fetch the first `ID` found, where the bit isn't set and whilst fetching also set the bit. So that no other instance of the script uses the same `ID` and no race condition is possible.

```
import _mssql
con = _mssql.connect(server='server', user='user', password='password', database='default')

#these two in a single command
con.execute_query('SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM tableA WHERE done=0')
con.execute_query('UPDATE tableA SET done=1 WHERE ID=\''+id_from_above+'\'')
for row in con:
    #row['ID'] contains nothing as it last used with the UPDATE, not the SELECT
    start_function(row['ID'])
```

edit (including the suggestion of wewesthemenace):

```
[...]
con.execute_query('UPDATE tableA SET done = 1 WHERE ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM tableA WHERE done = 0)')
for row in con:
    #row['ID'] contains nothing as it last used with the UPDATE, not the SELECT
    start_function(row['ID'])
```

Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00, i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2

edit 2:
The answered question lead me to a follow-up question: [While mssql query returns an affected ID use it in a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604709/while-mssql-query-returns-an-affected-id-use-it-in-a-while-loop)

Comment: You wanna look into **transactions** and **row-locking** for this. There's no easy _"chuck both queries in 1 `execute_query()` and you're good."_ solution (afaik). Good introduction I found is **[this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx)** that introduces it and explains **ACID** etc.

Comment: I've got a solution with a single execute_quer().. I'll edit the question and add my solution right now. But thank you very much for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible solution**, which works in my situation.

```
con.execute_query('UPDATE tableA SET done=1 OUTPUT INSERTED.ID WHERE ID=(SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM tableA WHERE done=0)')
for row in con:
    #row['ID'] is exactly one ID where the done bit wasn't set, but now is.
    start_function(row['ID'])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
UPDATE tableA SET done = 1 WHERE ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM tableA WHERE done = 0)
```

Comment: looks good but I assume I won't be able to `for row in con: start_function(row['ID'])`. To clarify myself, it does what it's supposed to, but I don't get the ID I just set the done bit on.