# While mssql query returns an affected ID use it in a while loop

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, while-loop

This is a follow-up question from ([Update and select in one operation in MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602777/update-and-select-in-one-operation-in-mssql))

I have a table with a column `ID` varchar(255) and a `done` bit. I fetch one `ID` where the `done` bit isn't set and set said bit in the same step. Then I'll process the `ID` and continue with the next.. I want to do this until no `ID` is left without the `done` bit set.

The code looks something like this:

```
import _mssql
con = _mssql.connect(server='server', user='user', password='password', database='default')

con.execute_query('UPDATE tableA SET done=1 OUTPUT INSERTED.ID WHERE ID=(SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM tableA WHERE done=0)')
for row in con:
    #row['ID'] is exactly one ID where the done bit wasn't set, but now is.
    current_id = row['ID']

while current_id:
     start_function(current_id)
else:
    print("ALL DONE")
```

How can I have fetch, assign and check the query above in the `while [...]`?
e.g. in pseudo-code:

```
while(current_id = row['ID'] for row in con.execute_query([...]):
     start_function(current_id)
else:
    print("ALL DONE")
```

Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00, i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2

Comment: The question is not to clear, are you looking for `UPDATE tableA SET done=1 OUTPUT INSERTED.ID WHERE ID in (SELECT  ID FROM tableA WHERE done=0)`

Comment: @bummi I edited the question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Still clear for me, but if I got you right `while current_id:` would have to be as block before `con.execute_query`

Comment: @bummi what do you mean by "*to be as as block before*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution. At least it seems to work for me.

I have to following two functions:

```
def get_next(con):
    con.execute_query('UPDATE tableA SET done=1 OUTPUT INSERTED.ID WHERE ID=(SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM tableA WHERE done=0)')
    for row in con:
        #row['ID'] is exactly one ID where the done bit wasn't set, but now is.
        current_id = row['ID']
    return current_id

def start_function(id):
    #do something here with the id.
    pass
```

then in the main

```
import _mssql
con = _mssql.connect(server='server', user='user', password='password', database='default')

id = get_next(con)
while current_id:
     start_function(id)
     id = get_next(con)
else:
    print("ALL DONE")
```